# Unable to post data to NodeJS using Axios in React form

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I want to get the ticket value from react form to nodeJS and then based on the ticket received, I have to perform some task and fetch the results back onto the front end. 
My code seems to be fine, but it isn't running in the environment.

form.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
class Formdata extends Component{
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          ticket:""
        };
      }
    onChanges(val){
        console.log(val);
        this.setState({
            ticket:val
        })
        console.log(this.state.ticket)
    }
    handleSubmit() {

        console.log(this.state.ticket)
        const var2= {
            tic:this.state.ticket
        };
        axios.post("/user",{
            var1: var2
        })
        .then((response)=> {
            console.log("Data submitted successfully");
         }).catch((error)=> {
            console.log("got errr while posting data", error);
         });
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} method="POST">
                    <br/>
                    <input type="text" id="ticket" name="ticket" onChange={e=>this.onChanges(e.target.value)} placeholder="Ticket Number"/>
                    <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Formdata;
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.post('/user',function(request,response){
  const query1=request.body.var1;
  console.log(query1)
  response.query1;
  });


const port = 5000;

app.listen(port, () => `Server running on port ${port}`);
```

Comment: Still getting: Cannot POST/

Comment: What is the problem exactly ? Is there any error ? is you server receiving the post request ?

Comment: As soon as I submit the form the browser shows this: 
Cannot POST/
Hence, the server is not receiving the POST request.

Comment: Before call your api from frontEnd, I hope you to try it first in postman.

Comment: using Postman, I'm able to send undefined requests

Comment: You can see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    axios.post("http://localhost:5000/user",{
        var1: var2
    })



const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
const bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.post('/user',function(request,response){
  const query1=request.body.var1;
  console.log(query1)
  response.query1;
  });


const port = 5000;

app.listen(port, () => `Server running on port ${port}`);
```

Comment: As soon as I submit the form the browser shows this: 
Cannot POST/
Hence, the server is not receiving the POST request.

Comment: Is your node server is running?

Comment: Check using Postman, the server is working or not. If possible create a GET route and check.

Answer (score 0):

You try code below:

```js
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.post('/user',function(request,response){
  const body =request.body;
  console.log(body);
  res.send(body);
  });

app.listen(5000, () => `Server running on port 5000`);
```

You can copy the code to your code and call api from your postman:

1. API URL: `localhost:5000/users`
2. Change method to: `POST` method
3. Don't forget to **add json object** to `body`
4. **Send request** to backend

I hope it's work.

Comment: Postman is perfectly able to send requests. There seems to be some issue with my form. it is not able to post.

Comment: Also response.send does nothing on /user

Comment: You say, there's no problem in backend. But I see your server.js, there's no body parser in there, that's why your request.body always `undefined`. But If you say, no problem in there, than you can see it on your network and console.log, what error messages you get there.

Comment: localhost:3000/user shows this
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: when the form is submitted

Comment: I still believe there is something wrong with my form, which is unable to post request. Because the server seems to be working fine with Postman

Comment: localhost:3000/user is `404`, because port in your server.js is `5000`, not `3000`. So, you can call: localhost:5000/user, not localhost:3000/user

Comment: Can you share your backend and frontend github link. Let me check it for you.

Comment: Exactly, cannot GET /user, because in your server.js is using method POST, not GET.

Comment: I'm afraid I wouldn't be able to share the github link, due to some issues. But I can surely post the current version of the code. If it works?

Answer (score 0):

Please use and check in the file:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
   extended: false
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```